# How do I click the button to send the desired value to the Angular 4 controller?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this HTML code:

```
 <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example" *ngFor="let techlist of technology">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="resList()">{{techlist.TechnologyRouteTitle}}</button>
  </div>
```

The technology has a view model:

```
public ComponentTypeId: number;
public ComponentTypeTitle: string;
public TechnologyRouteId: number;
```

Now there are 4 elements. They have a unique TechnologyRouteKey. By clicking on one of them I need to load a list of technologies. I have this function:

```
  resList(): void {
    this.TestService.getResearchList(this.filterResearchList)
      .then(response => {
        this.technology = response.Object;
      });
  }
```

this.filterResearchList Has such a view model:

```
public CompanyId: number;
public TechnologyRouteKey: string;
```

The company ID is always the same, but the TechnologyRouteKey needs to be changed depending on the button you pressed, how do I do this? Already an hour spent on it, does not work. Which way to look?

Comment: check answer and let me know if you required any thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to pass value then you should pass in click function as argument like this

```
(click)="resList(argument)" //in template html file
```

which means it should be like this if i am correct (check click function i passed route id)

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group" 
     aria-label="Basic example" *ngFor="let techlist of technology">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" 
      (click)="resList(techlist.TechnologyRouteId)">
               {{techlist.TechnologyRouteTitle}}</button>
  </div>
```

and ts file

```
 resList(argument): void {
 }
```